# SAP CRM / Customer service module as a ticketing system

Tags: module, licensing, sap-crm

I'm using SAP Logon 770 and I have 2 questions related to CRM and Customer Service modules.

The questions:

1. Can I use Logistics > Customer Service module as a helpdesk ticketing system for a University?
2. Under IMG structure I found CRM module in my SAP logon 770 is it possible to enable it or do I have to ask for further licensing?

Thanks in advance